# How to return variables in Python Flask function and use them in another function?

Tags: python, html, forms, function, flask

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def value():

    port=22
    para1 = request.form['input1']
    para2 = request.form['input2']
    para3 = request.form['input3']
    ssh_client=paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    ssh_client.connect(hostname=para1,port=port,username=para2,password=para3)
    return render_template('index.html')
```

I have a function like this that receives values from the HTML form, and I want to pass the value of `para1`, `para2`, `para3` to anther function.

I try `return render_template('index.html'), para1, para2, para3` or 
`return render_template('index.html', para1, para2, para3)`

Both of them do not work.

Comment: `return render_template('index.html'), para1, para2, para3` is clearly not going to work, that's passing a single argument to `render_template` and returning a tuple from `value`. Could you expand on how `render_template('index.html', para1, para2, para3)` doesn't work? Give a [mcve].

Comment: To exactly which function you want provide that variables?

Comment: According to flask docs: *All you have to do is provide the name of the template and the variables you want to pass to the template engine as **keyword arguments**.* `render_template('index.html', para1=para1, para2=para2, para3=para3)`

Comment: @KennyAires No, that's `SyntaxError`.

Comment: my bad, you're right